# Make navigation table bar into hover dropdown using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

currently I am editing a website page that has a navigation bar in a table. I want to expand one of the items into a hover drop down item. But I cannot seem to align and style it to match the current format

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <title>NPC RESOURCES BERHAD</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-43048026-3', 'npc.com.my');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body><script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script><!--
<script>
    $.backstretch("images/bgred2.jpg");
</script>
-->
<div align="center">
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" width="780">
 <tbody>
  <tr valign="bottom">
   <th colspan="2" scope="col">
   <div align="left"><img height="148" src="images/npcgif.gif" width="780" /> <img height="49" src="images/NPC.jpg" width="780" /> <img height="18" src="images/layout2_03.jpg" width="230" />
   <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="10" width="532">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="index.htm">MAIN</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="companyprofile.htm">COMPANY PROFILE</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="ourbusiness.htm">OUR BUSINESS</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterselectedlink"><a href="corporategovernance.htm">CORPORATE COVERNANCE</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="financialhl.htm">INVESTORS RELATIONS</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="career.htm">CAREER</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT</a></div>
      </th>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>
   </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td height="300" valign="top">
   <div align="center"></div>

   <div align="left"></div>

   <div align="justify">
   <table align="center" background="images/bgsmall.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="90%">
    <tbody>
     <tr valign="top">
      <td>
      <p class="paragraphboldblack">The requested webpage was not found.</p>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <div align="center"><img height="69" src="images/layout2_14.jpg" width="780" /></div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make "CORPORATE GOVERNANCE" into a hover drop down item, so when you hover over it, several other options are available. I am currently using cPanel.

Can anyone help??

Thanks so much.

Comment: You first problem is that you have a table used for layout. This is going to make this more difficult that it needs to be. You also need to show us what styling you have tried to date. "But I cannot seem to align and style it to match the current format"... what is the current format? How can we help you match it we don't know what it is. At the moment this reads as  "please code this for me", not "here's what I've tried, where did I go wrong?"

Comment: Hi Jon, any chance you could take a look at my reply and let me know where I've gone wrong?

Comment: To find out styles on the existing site, most browsers have Developer Tools available by pressing F12. There you will find an option to inspect elements to find out what styles are applied to it This will help you match the existing styling. You should be editing your question, or asking a whole new question instead of extending your question via answers.

Comment: Sorry, Jon. I wasn't sure how to respond. Your instructions have been noted. And thanks for the F12 suggestion, it really helped. I appreciate that you've been so patient given that I've been asking very basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage was as such when I was instructed to edit the whole website. I have zero experience in all things tech so I basically Googled "how to's" on what I could do. Like you said, most advice online have not been keen on using tables as a navigation bar, but I dare not change that as I don't know how to adjust the styling.

What I've tried:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <title>NPC RESOURCES BERHAD</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-43048026-3', 'npc.com.my');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body><script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script><!--
<script>
    $.backstretch("images/bgred2.jpg");
</script>
-->
<div align="center">
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" width="780">
 <tbody>
  <tr valign="bottom">
   <th colspan="2" scope="col">
   <div align="left"><img height="148" src="images/npcgif.gif" width="780" /> <img height="49" src="images/NPC.jpg" width="780" /> <img height="18" src="images/layout2_03.jpg" width="230" />
   <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="10" width="532">
       <style type="text/css">.dropbtn {
                                background-color: #4CAF50;
                                color: white;
                                padding: 16px;
                                font-size: 16px;
                                border: none;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown {
                                position: relative;
                                display: inline-block;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown-content {
                                display: none;
                                position: absolute;
                                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                                min-width: 160px;
                                box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                                z-index: 1;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown-content a {
                                color: black;
                                padding: 12px 16px;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                display: block;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
                            
                            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                                display: block;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                                background-color: #3e8e41;
                            }
                </style>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="index.htm">MAIN</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="companyprofile.htm">COMPANY PROFILE</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="ourbusiness.htm">OUR BUSINESS</a></div>
      </th>
      <div align="center" class="masterselectedlink">
                        <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn"><div position="col"></div>CORPORATE GOVERNANCE</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
                        </div>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">
               <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="financialhl.htm">INVESTORS RELATIONS</a></div>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">
               <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="career.htm">CAREER</a></div>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">
               <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT</a></div>
               </th>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

<div align="center"></div>

<div align="left"></div>

<div align="justify">
<table align="center" background="images/bgsmall.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="90%">
 <tbody>
  <tr valign="top">
   <td>
   <p class="paragraphboldblack">The requested webpage was not found.</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div align="center"><img height="69" src="images/layout2_14.jpg" width="780" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the button is outside the table. I understand the colouring and format is different, but what am I supposed to do to get it to be in the same original position, just with dropdown items? I'd like to work with the current table, instead of redefining the whole format, since the whole website has the navigation menu as a table.

Thanks again

Comment: Here's the thing "I have zero experience in all things tech", this has lead you to googling for solutions and copying and pasting the results into your code with no real understanding of what you are doing. You have ended up with code that is some what broken. The issue is you have the only valid children of `tr` tags are `th` and `td` tags. You also have an unclosed `th` tag. What you should be doing is starting at the beginning and doing some basic HTML and CSS tutorial, so you can understand the issue.

Comment: I feel for you as you have been tasked to edit a website with no tech experience. To complicate matters you a dealing with code that is now far from what is considered best practice. If you had more experience you would see that trying to put a CSS dropdown into a table is going to be difficult. The *best long term* approach is to get rid of the tables and start again. Understandably daunting for someone with no experience.

Comment: Hello Jon, I appreciate the feedback. If I were to take up your suggestion to scrap the table, the entire layout would be different. I am neither experienced nor learned enough to deal with such a massive overhaul of change. What I HAVE managed to do in the time before you replied was to amend the errors I made in my blind copy/paste attempts. The dropdown menu is FINALLY in the correct spot (HALLELUJAH YOU HAVE NO IDEA HOW HAPPY I WAS), the issue now is that I cannot get the font and colour to match. I cannot see what the original style was. Please see my update and hopefully you'll know?

Answer (score 0):

To update: I've managed to fit the "CORPORATE GOVERNANCE" in the place I want it to be. But how do I figure out what the old font, colour, size etc of the page so I can make it match?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <title>NPC RESOURCES BERHAD</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-43048026-3', 'npc.com.my');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body><script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script><!--
<script>
    $.backstretch("images/bgred2.jpg");
</script>
-->
<div align="center">
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" width="780">
 <tbody>
  <tr valign="bottom">
   <th colspan="2" scope="col">
   <div align="left"><img height="148" src="images/npcgif.gif" width="780" /> <img height="49" src="images/NPC.jpg" width="780" /> <img height="18" src="images/layout2_03.jpg" width="230" />
   <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="10" width="532">
       <style type="text/css">.dropbtn {
                                background-color: #ffffff;
                                color: black;
                                padding: 16px;
                                font-size: 16px;
                                border: none;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown {
                                position: relative;
                                display: inline-block;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown-content {
                                display: none;
                                position: absolute;
                                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                                min-width: 160px;
                                box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                                z-index: 1;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown-content a {
                                color: black;
                                padding: 12px 16px;
                                text-decoration: none;
                                display: block;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ccd4cc}
                            
                            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
                                display: block;
                            }
                            
                            .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
                                background-color: #ccd4cc;
                            }
                </style>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="index.htm">MAIN</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="companyprofile.htm">COMPANY PROFILE</a></div>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
      <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="ourbusiness.htm">OUR BUSINESS</a></div>
      </th>
      <td class="dropdown">
      <div align="center" class="masterselectedlink">
                        <div class="dropdown"><button class="dropbtn">CORPORATE GOVERNANCE</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
                        </div>
               <th scope="col">
               <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="financialhl.htm">INVESTORS RELATIONS</a></div>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">
               <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="career.htm">CAREER</a></div>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">
               <div align="center" class="masterlink"><a href="contact.htm">CONTACT</a></div>
               </th>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>

<div align="center"></div>

<div align="left"></div>

<div align="justify">
<table align="center" background="images/bgsmall.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="90%">
 <tbody>
  <tr valign="top">
   <td>
   <p class="paragraphboldblack">The requested webpage was not found.</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div align="center"><img height="69" src="images/layout2_14.jpg" width="780" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would really REALLY appreciate any advice on how to style this. Thanks very much in advance.

Joanne